# Which is more correct? Plenty of room or Plenty of rooms

Tags: grammar, differences

I want to understand the difference between "Plenty of room" and "plenty of rooms".

For example 
Of course, you must stay with us. There’s plenty of room and we’ll pick you up at the airport.

Comment: Both are fine. It just depends what the speaker wants to convey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone says to a potential guest, for example, a relative who may be staying in their *home*, they would normally use the singular, **room** with "plenty of".

> We have *plenty of room*. Bring the kids.

It means "We have beds, cots, sofa-bed, carpeted floor and sleeping bags, whatever--enough to accommodate you."

The plural, "plenty of rooms", is normally used of commercial establishments like hotels, motels, inns, bed-and-breakfasts:

> In the off-season we have plenty of rooms available.

Answer (score 1):

I think "plenty of rooms" is quite commonly used.

Example: There were plenty of rooms available for booking when I checked.

"There's Plenty of Room at the Bottom": This is a lecture given by a famous physicist at one of the annual American Physical Society meeting.

Answer (score 1):

> Plenty of room

This refers to the non-count usage of the noun **room**.  It refers to the amount of space in one given place.

> Plenty of rooms

This refers to the count usage of the noun **room**.  A room in this usage refers to a divided place in a house.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot. I would put you as accepted answer if I could accept two answers. thanks again